# Which ARM compiler for a Cortex-M4, arm-none-eabi, generates the least code space?

Tags: compiler-construction, arm, space

Well, I think the title says it all, but the web page complains that the message body is missing.

There were valuable discussions here about code space optimization, but I wonder what compiler (GCC, Keil, IAR, CLang, etc.) would do the best job in it. I have compared four so far (all free), Atmel Studio GCC, Yagarto, CodeSourcery Light, and ARM GNU Embedded Tools (found at launchpad.net). As the source I use part of OpenSSL 1.0.1c configured for no OS and massaged. There is no big difference, about 10% (470k to 520k, -O1) for the optimization levels I used (-O1 and -Os). I wonder whether there are compilers out there that beat the (mainly gcc) crowd by 25% or so.

Comment: Atmel Studio **GCC**, Yagarto (newlib), Code Sourcery and **ARM GNU Embedded tools** are all **GCC**.  I imagine the `gcc --version` matters.  Ie, you have tried *four versons* of gcc.  I don't know if LLVM can be configured for *newlib*, but at least find a different code generator.  `-O1` is not really interesting; `-O2` shouldn't create more code.  `-Os` is most relevant for code space.

Comment: I have seen -O2 generate smaller binaries than -Os for various compilers so dont assume that compiling for size makes the smallest.  You should get an eval from arm in particular, also keil, iar, and any other that you can get an eval for...Like any other benchmark though it is heavily dependent on your code, so there is not going to be a "best" compiler for size or speed or anything else.

Comment: Last I checked, RVCT was *significantly* better than GCC (and I think RVCT was outputting ARM and GCC was outputting Thumb). Some of it may have been due to large runtime libraries, YMMV, etc. It isn't free, though.

Comment: @tc. how is that relevant then? given that the cortex-m4 which the question is specifically about only supports the thumb/thumb2 and *not* the arm instruction set.

Comment: The whole point of Thumb is that it's smaller than ARM (except for particularly odd code), which would mean RVCT Thumb < RVCT ARM < GCC Thumb < GCC ARM.

Answer (score 1):

The Keil/ARM compiler, commercially available (not free), is probably the best in terms of code-size. It's probably not 25% ahead of GCC though.

To get really good code-size you need to look at options for getting rid of unused code aggressively like -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  --gc-sections in gcc or --split-sections in armcc.